# Turn wifi on using F keys

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop, hotkeys

I was wondering can I change the function of a F-key on my Dell Inspiron 3576 laptop? For Example can I make the F7 key turns the wifi on/off? Thanks.
Note: windows: 10.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable/enable the WiFi interface using the
[netsh command](https://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html).

The syntax of the two commands is:

```
netsh interface set interface "YOUR-ADAPTER-NAME" disable
netsh interface set interface "YOUR-ADAPTER-NAME" enable
```

You can find the name of the WiFi interface by using the command:

```
netsh interface show interface
```

You may store these command in two `.bat` files on the desktop, right-click each,
choose Properties, Shortcut tab, and set the "Shortcut key".
For example, you could use <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366591/how-to-toggle-airplane-mode-in-windows-8-from-cmd-or-powershell for use of PowerShell script.